# Missing shared library - android

Tags: android, google-maps

I try test my app on device (Ainol Crystal) with Android 4.1.1. In emulator everything works ok but on device I get:

```
12-14 12:22:13.437: E/PackageManager(3372): Package com.capgemini.navi4uni requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
```

Native Google Maps app is installed and it works. There are also files:

```
/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.xml
/system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
```

App uses api version 1 (depricated). What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maps library might not be present in the device you are using. Try to export the library along with the apk. In eclipse you can do this by RightclickOnProject->Build Path->Configure BuildPath->Order and Export->.. now check the google maps library..